# Best method for getting bulk address information (total sent, received, and final balance)

Tags: blockchain, address, python

I need to go through a large list (about 100 000) of bitcoin addresses, and, if they have a final balance, find that as well as the total sent and recieved. I am working in python, and I have looked through the various API's, but so far I have found the best solution to be getting the JSON data from https://blockchain.info/

I use:

```
urllib.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?cors=true&active="+testStr)
```

where testStr is up to 23 addresses, separated by |

This returns a page which I dump into a json and parse for the data I need. I am just wondering if there is any faster method to get this information, rather than multiple calls to blockchain.info?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do scientific or academical research, you probably won't use blockchain.info. Because this would mean you basically trust bitcoin.info as blockchain source. **It really would consider creating and querying your own blockchain copy by installing and syncing a Bitcoin-Core node**.

A simple python (or different language) JSON RPC script could solve your problem.
(requires a synced bitcoin-core node)

1. Add 1000 (of the 100'000) addresses over RPC call `importaddress`
2. Get balance of each address by calling `listreceivedbyaddress
3. Stop bitcoin-core
4. Delete wallet.dat
5. Start bitcoin-core

--> go back to 1)

You might increase or decrease the address frame (1000) depending on your system CPU/Mem/Disk resources.

Comment: Hi. 
Thank you for the input!
I have got to try and code this first, but is it likely to be slower or faster than questioning blockchain? At the moment, my main concern is speed.

Comment: Very likely that accessing blockchain.info is faster because they have a per-address index. You need to rescan after every frame (+/-1000 address) which can take serval minutes. But blockchain.info might block your access because of high traffic or similar.